# 48 hours is too long to enable the add a bounty

Tags: feature-request, bounties

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why can’t I just offer a bounty for a question right off the bat?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3330/why-cant-i-just-offer-a-bounty-for-a-question-right-off-the-bat)

As most of us know now, when a question has a bounty, it can gain more answers faster than the questions without a bounty.  It just so happens that I needed an answer to [my question in SU](https://superuser.com/questions/53677/how-to-resize-a-windows-vista-partition-to-use-the-extra-space-for-dual-booting-w) and I need to get a good answer really really fast. But since there is a threshold for giving a bounty, I will still have to wait longer instead of getting the answers faster. I think 48 hours is too long. Maybe we could at least make it 24 hours.

Comment: See "Why can’t I just offer a bounty for a question right off the bat?" at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3330/why-cant-i-just-offer-a-bounty-for-a-question-right-off-the-bat

Comment: Sounds like `status-declined`

Comment: Why did you need it really really fast?

Comment: This is not an exact duplicate of the linked question. The linked question wants to completely remove the waiting period.

Comment: Good point, Pekka!