# Let us vote to close posts with bounties on them

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, bounties, vote-to-close

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Allow users to vote to close bountied questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121448/allow-users-to-vote-to-close-bountied-questions)

It seems pretty ridiculous that someone can filibuster for a week (or longer if they have rep to burn) simply by offering a bounty on a question.  I don't understand how subverting an entire community (with or without intent) is compatible with SE's semi-democratic process.  (Then again, I don't understand how it's compatible with the United States' form of government either :P).  Can we get this feature removed?  <s>The bounty should be refunded to the offerer in this case, I would think, since the bounty period is cut short.</s> (Do whatever you want with the bounty, see comments.)

I'm bringing this up specifically because of [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/66536/6066) on Gaming, which I find to fail nearly every criterion for a good on-topic question.  I don't think I should need to flag it and attempt to convince a mod to take it upon themselves; the community ought to be quite capable of dealing with this if they agree with my take on the question.

---

(I assumed this would be a duplicate request, but couldn't find anything ... let me know if you do.)

Comment: +1, I *hate* this.  When a bountied question gets closed, some of the rep could just go back to the user who applied the bounty.  But not all of it, because he should know better.

Comment: [You didn't search hard enough :P](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121448/allow-users-to-vote-to-close-bountied-questions)

Comment: @JeffMercado Lol, and I've upvoted at some point in the past apparently! Thanks....

Comment: Yeah, yeah, everyone loves to talk about punishing the guy with the audacity to "protect" his question with a bounty. In this case, the question sat untouched for over a month, got bountied, got two answers in response to the bounty. Closing it now (particularly with a bounty refund) punishes the *answerers* more than the asker.

Comment: @Shog9 In this case I'm not saying he did it to protect the question (though that has been done previously on Gaming). But what does it have to do with punishing the user? Closing a question isn't a punishment. The fact that the question was missed (in the absolute MASS of Diablo 3 questions) doesn't mean it should stay open or that the bounty should keep it open.  You didn't provide any reason why a bounty should protect a question like this.

Comment: @MatthewRead: that was more in response to GnomeSlice's comment about not refunding the whole amount because "he shoulda known better". BTW: still don't see *a single comment or even a flag* about what's wrong with that question *on that question*...

Comment: @Shog9 Gotcha. I would take that as evidence of the negative effect the bounty is having -- people often leave comments when they take action. Whining about futility is probably best left to chat and Meta where it is now :P, but I'm sure we could muster up some critical comments for the question if that's needed; I've added one.

Comment: @Matthew: again, in *over a month* no one has criticized that question publicly on Gaming. I checked - it actually *had* four close votes at one time, but they expired... Again, without a single comment identifying the problem with the question. Not saying anyone should *whine* about it, but your frustration with the bounty could've potentially been avoided completely if the question had been fixed - or the author at least made aware - a month ago.

Comment: @Shog9 Fair enough. Still, I don't think that has any bearing on whether a bounty should disable close voting.

Comment: @Matthew: your specific suggestion (that closing would refund the bounty) does... The whole point of bounties is to sweeten the deal a bit for answerers, get more attention for a neglected question - if you answer a bountied question in good faith and the bounty is revoked, that would tend to hurt your trust in such a system. Of course, if you have reason to believe the question would be closed, that's a bit different - but in the example you gave, there was no visible indication that anything was amiss.

Comment: @Shog9 If that minor sidepoint is the reason you status-declined this, I'll remove it.  I just figured that was the natural thing to do with the bounty -- if you were to post a bounty in good faith and it was revoked without the rep being restored, that would tend to hurt your trust in such a system.  No?  There are tradeoffs here, the details are up to you guys to decide on -- my issue is with bounties disabling close voting, I thought that was clear.

Comment: Might as well discuss this on Mark's proposal, since this variation has now been suggested there as well. But for the record, I don't think it's "minor" at all - remember, the original justification for even *having* a system for bounties was to encourage answers to questions where answering would require more than the usual amount of effort. Revoking that *after* someone's already put the effort in breaks that contract. This isn't a side-effect-free "undo" you're proposing here.

Comment: @Shog9 I don't think the bounty system works very well to begin with, but that's a different discussion :P. It was minor in terms of how I wrote my post -- again, my proposal is to allow close votes when there is a bounty. I, personally, am not very concerned with what happens to the bounty, and I don't want that to detract from my point about voting.

Comment: @Matthew: To be honest, I rather dislike the entire concept of bounties, hence my opposition to anything that would weaken the constraints placed on them. But yes, totally different topic ;-)

Comment: You can't offer a bounty for 48 hours after the question is asked, so just close it in the first 24 hours.

Comment: @Kevin Let me know when you've invented a time machine.

Comment: @MatthewRead my point is that you have two full days to catch bad questions before they can be "protected" by bounties. If they make it past that, they can't be that bad, and if they do still need to be deleted just flag for a mod.

Comment: Yeah, that's not how it works.  Plenty of bad questions get through on all the bigger sites, it's too much to be on top of perfectly.  Besides, borderline questions are exactly the ones you want to be closed through community consensus and not by a mod.