# Associating bounty to a question

Tags: support, bounties

Some of the questions don't get answered soon, in such cases it would be preferable to provide a bounty for answering such questions. Is there a mechanism to do it, without waiting for a few days?

Comment: Or, You like to do feature request? If so, please rephrase and tag it with feature-request. I am not sure, there is a dup though.

Comment: As to why you can't, you can check out the answers to these duplicate questions: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34663/why-do-you-have-to-wait-a-certain-period-before-you-can-start-a-bounty/34701#34701 or http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3330/why-cant-i-just-offer-a-bounty-for-a-question-right-off-the-bat .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. You still have to wait 2 days.

In [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq),

> If, after 2 days, you still don't have
>   an answer you like, you can  offer a
>   bounty

Comment: It would be nice if a bounty could be offered, for example, if *there are no answers* after let's say, one day, or 12 hours.

Comment: @idigas: if the question is *that* time-sensitive maybe the asker should be on IRC, or on the phone with paid support.

Comment: Can you point me to information on paid support with this site.

Comment: @quack - could you eleborate on paid support you mentioned to him?

Comment: @Joshua - I think he mean different site for paid support, not stack overflow

Comment: @Joshua - my apologies.  i meant that you could pay *someone* to help you; i did not necessarily mean you could pay someone *here at this site* to help.

Comment: @quack, I just know you are ~quack , http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44145/a-last-tribute-to-the-tilde , I missed ~ too :-)