# How quickly are questions answered on SO?

Tags: discussion, statistics, questions, responses

I don't have the SQL chops to do this query, so I'm hoping someone else might.  I'd like to 'bin' all the questions on SO based on how long until they received their first upvoted answer.  Not the time to the upvote, the time to the first answer that eventually received an upvote - in other words I don't want to include answers with no upvote in the time calculation.

The bins could be linear or logarithmic, whichever is easier to implement.  If someone can even just give me a starter bit of SQL that works on stackql or another existing SO data dump site to work with I'll fiddle with it...

Comment: How about those that were later closed as dupes but not quick enough because all the repping users just posted dupe answers?

Comment: It depends on when it was posted - see the graph in this answer http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3330/why-cant-i-just-offer-a-bounty-for-a-question-right-off-the-bat/3333#3333

Comment: @random We gotta start somewhere :)

Comment: Those at 3000 rep and over should at least pretend to want to clean up the place. Those well under can at least have a shot. @mrs

Comment: @random: says who? Clean up tasks (such as closing duplicates) is voluntary and not mandatory.. (Like everything else here)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've got a couple of graphs at the bottom of my [SO stats page](http://hewgill.com/~greg/stackoverflow/stack_overflow/stats.html) that attempts to graph this. With the wide variance in time to answer, I've used a log scale on the bin sizes.

[image]

[image]

These graphs don't try to do the "earlier answer that eventually received an upvote", but just "earliest answer" and "accepted answer".

The snippet of SQL the graph uses (against my database, which happens to be PostgreSQL) is shown above the graph.

Answer (score 1):

The result will be different on different tag names.
Questions on general topics, for instance, "PHP HTML Entities" get their answers in minutes or sometimes even in seconds. SharePoint questions [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150526/is-it-possible-to-customize-a-sharepoint-list-form-so-that-selecting-a-bdc-value) can live for days and no answer received at all.

Comment: That's true - but this is for a very broad generalization.  Once we've got a nice binned set of numbers we can drill down if there are obvious areas that need more exploration.