# Why can't new questions be bountied on the spot?

Tags: feature-request, bounties

It would make it possible for the site communities to develop "house rules" on which they handle the bountied questions differently.

An example scenario: consider a hard science site, which has a policy that they disallow questions looking as a homework question. If the bounty could be allowed on the spot, with asking the question, they could make an exception with the bountied questions.

Comment: [Related, possible duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/137486/21960)

Comment: Hold on... you're suggesting allowing on-the-spot bounties to get around asking questions which aren't on-topic? Surely that's exactly one of the reasons not to allow it

Comment: @Ramhound I think it is a shorteyed result. Wanting a bounty on homework questions would also mean, that the OP has worked a lot already to produce the reputation for that bounty. Thus, a bountied question would come together with a lot of upvoted content, what the OP already had to produced for the rep for the bounty.

Answer (score 6):

You seem to misunderstand. This is no "Do work, get points, spend points on getting your work done by others"-type of network.

Bounties are a tool to make your question more attractive, gather more attention etc., but not as a payment. Reward yes, payment no.

I think that most (if not all) sites would be heavily opposed to such a mechanism, as homework questions are not what we want on here. Homework questions tend to be too specific to hold any significant value for future readers.

Comment: I think here is the time for you to finally read the relevants parts of the SE help pages / policy. Your hairsplitting arguments are contridicting also them.

Comment: @peterh Funny to hear that from you. This is the general stance of the community on homework questions & the value of reputation, and my " hairsplitting" arguments do not in the least "contridict" them. I think it's time for you to accept that homework questions are not something that we, the community, want, period.

Comment: My post is about to make bounties from the questions on the spot, and not only after a delay. The homework is only a specific case of the more general initiative. The bounties could serve as catalizators for new users to provide worthy content *before* they ask for some more great, while it would filter out the OPs not wanting to do this.

Comment: @peterh The problem with instantly applying bounties is that bountied questions are protected from being closed, just in case you didn't know. This would mean that users could post off-topic questions, add a bounty to them & not have to worry about it being closed by anyone except for moderators. That's why instant bounties are nothing we want, it would add **no value** whilst providing a way to bypass the process of quality assurance on the SE-network.

Comment: Well, that is okay. I think, bounty shouldn't protect a question from closure, but if a bountied question is closed, the rep (or half of the rep) should be paid back. Well, it would cause a lot of whining. Ok, I am thinking on it more.

Answer (score 6):

So you want it to be possible for bounties to be immediate. And, if these are abused to prevent quick closure, to have systems around that. Sounds to me as  a way to make things more complicated than necessary.

The 2-day delay isn't only there to give a community time to close a question. It is also there to prevent the front page from becoming a rush to award the highest bounty.

I don't see a need to award bounties immediately. It's better to encourage users to polish their question first. Or edit it with the things they find after posting. That will also bump the question, and in a way that (hopefully) makes it easier to answer. And makes the question easier to find for the next user with the same problem.

On the busy sites like Stack Overflow or Ask Ubuntu, I could imagine shortening the time for a bounty - for example, 24 hours instead of 48. But in general, I see no need for the ability to bounty a question right after posting.

If a community decides that a question is out of the scope of their site, but should remain open anyway - we have per-site metas where they can rule on that. This should be extremely rare however - we got where we are by being strict about site scope. Off-topic questions that still convey value can be migrated or put under a historical lock, depending on the precise situation.

Comment: Getting the rep for the bounty is work, hard work. Saying that the bounties would be *"abused to prevent quick closure"* is surreal in the light of their high cost.

Comment: @peterh Depends on the site, and on how honest one is going to be. For a voting ring it's not that hard, for them the main problem is avoiding detection.