# I need an answer. Could I start a bounty right away?

Tags: support, bounties

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why can't I just offer a bounty for a question right off the bat?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3330/why-cant-i-just-offer-a-bounty-for-a-question-right-off-the-bat)

Not long ago, I asked the question [How should I modify this SQL statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3824203/how-should-i-modify-this-sql-statement)

I could not get the answer I was looking for until I offered a 400-rep bounty.
I then got the answer in less than 5 minutes.

So I would love to have the option of setting the bounty at the time of writing the question, in order to get an answer more quickly.