# Want to create a bounty for already asked question

Tags: support, unanswered-questions, bounties

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

I have a question that was asked 20 minutes back. I need the answers fast. So I thought of giving it a bounty and getting more attention. But, I do not see a start bounty option.

I have enough reputation.

Please let me know, how to start a bounty in this case.

Comment: You can't place bounties right away, no matter how much reputation you have.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3330/why-cant-i-just-offer-a-bounty-for-a-question-right-off-the-bat

Comment: @Popular, once again I disagree that those are duplicates.

Comment: @jjnguy Er. Your answer is copied from that exact page

Comment: @Michael, yup.  But just because a question has answers on it that answer a different question, doesn't mean that the two questions are duplicates.

Comment: @jjnguy When did that change? We've closed meta questions as duplicates of the FAQ entry that answers them for ages

Comment: @jjn, I agree with Michael, but you did remind me that I never found the source for closing subset questions as dupes. Perhaps I got distracted by work or something shiny. I'll have another look. If I don't find it, maybe you should open an MSO post about it. At the very least it'll make Grace Note cough up the link, if the point of failure is actually my lack of search skill.

Comment: Ah, found it right away, today: ["if a user asks, 'What does the IP address 128.0.1.1/24 mean?' it’s OK to close that as a duplicate of a more general question like 'What do IP addresses of the form a.b.c.d/e mean?'"](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/the-wikipedia-of-long-tail-programming-questions/)

Comment: @Popular, from the Exact Same blog post you linked to - "But it’s not OK to close it as a duplicate of a twenty-seven page guide to netmasks."  I think FAQ entries fall into that category.

Comment: @Michael, see comment above.

Comment: I certainly wouldn't close this way on a normal site, I don't think most people would, but this is hardly a new policy on meta

Comment: @Michael, fair enough.  I don't like the idea of closing this question though, because it allows the question to be deleted.

Comment: @jjn, I saw that, but I disagree that 27-page netmask guides are equivalent to FAQ entries. Our FAQs are intended to be user-friendly, not scary super-technical tomes. Nine times out of ten in these MSO cases, the problem is that the asker didn't know where to find the information, not that the asker found the resource and didn't understand it.

Comment: Also, it's my understanding that Meta encourages aggressive closing while discouraging deletion in cases like these, so that other searchers have "signposts" with a variety of search terms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work):

> ### How do I start a bounty? When can I start a bounty?
>
> A bounty can be started on a question two days after the question was asked.
>
> ...