# I would like to see the threshold lowered (in time, not reputation) for starting a bounty

Tags: feature-request, bounties

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why can't I just offer a bounty for a question right off the bat?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3330/why-cant-i-just-offer-a-bounty-for-a-question-right-off-the-bat)

I have asked a "[big questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269999/rdlc-report-2008-in-vs-2010-reportviewer-appears-with-no-report-or-data)" (By "big" I mean long, involved and somewhat complicated). In 7 hours I have gotten 12 views, and not so much as a comment. Also, no votes to close it, no snide remarks about it being a 'dumb question' and nobody has pointed out that the solution is to add a semi-colon to the end of line 3... So I think it a "good question.

Now, I appreciate that it is a "big question" and therefore would like to offer a bounty on this question, a privilege for which I have earned the require 'reputation', but I have to wait 2 DAYS to do so.

It is, after all, "My Reputation", why should I be required to wait to offer a bounty to (hopefully) entice a skilled developer to take the time to understand and hopefully answer my question? Not to mention I am in kind of a hurry, I might like to put a staged bounty, answer it TODAY and get 200 points, tomorrow, 175, etc..

In summary I have two feature requests:
 1. Reputation Qualified users should be able to offer a bounty as soon as they post a question if they wish.
 2. Users should be able to offered a "diminishing" bounty in an attempt to speed up an answer. 
(and maybe even a 3rd, at least for discussion, the ability to split bounties to multiple answers that meet my needs.)

Comment: I read your question over, and I'm not sure what "technique" you're talking about in the first sentence. Additionally, it seems like an obscure topic likely to not get an answer after only 13 views.

Comment: I'd be happy if a "post a bounty _NOW_" option burned three times the reputation points vs "post a bounty in 48 hours" burning two times the reputation points.

Comment: @sixlettervariables Your comment about technique would make a fine comment on the question itself (and it is building and populating the ReportViewer and the LocalReport separately from the page and then adding the control to the page only after it has been defined in the controller.) And that obscurity of topic is all the more reason to offer a bounty earlier, attract those who might know.

Comment: @sixlettervariables it is only '1/2' a duplicate.

Comment: Do not expect a hard problem to get an immediate answer. You can hire consultants if it's truly an emergency. Otherwise, wait your turn, set your bounty, and wait another six days before anyone even notices. In other words, even if you could set a bounty immediately, you still wouldn't get an answer for several days, if that.

Comment: @Cos: I went back and edited your tags to pop it up on more folks screens. I also edited down the code to fit better on screen. I don't know enough about RDLC to participate but I'm pushing this towards the folks on my team who do.

Comment: @Cos: in the future check the number of questions per tag and followers per tag. [tag:.rdlc] is a ghost town whereas [tag:rdlc] is better, and [tag:reporting-services] has tons more.

Comment: Join the ranks of those who wish SO worked differently.  But it doesn't.  So go back to asking and answering questions.

Answer (score 0):

Idk about you, but in my experience bounties only attract lots of attention at the **end** of the week, unless they're really large...