# Allow high-rep users to almost immediately offer bounties, though at an extra cost

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, bounties

Sometimes programmers need answers fast. I believe that high-reputation users should have the possibility to get a question featured within a few hours instead of the current two days (thanks @agf). There should, though, be an additional cost for doing this. My suggestion is that it should cost triple the amount of reputation. This means that one would need to spend 300 reputation to set 100 reputation bounty on a question.

Comment: I'd support maybe a few hours, but "immediately" will needlessly clog up the "featured" tab with questions that would have been answered anyway.

Comment: @agf. I agree, and I have updated the idea using your idea.

Comment: Related: [Why can't I just offer a bounty for a question right off the bat?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3330)

Comment: I would support the idea if it is not immediately but half an hour.

Comment: Do we currently have an issue with getting quick answers on well-worded questions? My experience has always been the opposite: anything but the most obscurely worded and niche-tagged question gets answers very quickly indeed. That said, I predominantly hang out in popular tags like C++ and C#.

Comment: @Razlebe Yes, that can be a problem from time to time, and often, an answer that arrives after several days is too late. You are right that I use more niche languages and have niche problems.

Comment: I doubt a bit that niche questions would get answers much faster if bountied. When there is only a small number of people knowing the answer and looking at your niche tags, this number will not much increase by putting a bounty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am declining this for a few reasons:

1. There is no point having a bounty on a question that is already perfectly adequately answered, in most cases questions are answered just fine without bounties.
2. It leaves a  a bad taste, "if you want your question **really** answered you better fork out 500 rep when asking it".
3. It introduces some loopholes by making it more complicated to close and move off topic questions to other sites. (mods need to refund and do the move themselves giving them more work)