# Privilege idea - post bounty sooner than 2 days

Tags: feature-request, bounties, privileges

It would be nice if there was a privilege you could earn which would let you post bounties on questions sooner than 2 days.  That could come in handy for time sensitive questions, and on higher volume sites a question can get scrolled down off the list of new questions quite rapidly.

Thoughts?

EDIT: I don't mean instantly, but some time sooner than 2 days.

Comment: If not 2 days, what then? 4 hours? A day?

Comment: @PatrickHofman My thought is at least a couple hours, but maybe at most a day but I was kind of leaving it open ended in case someone had a reason a particular time.  I think at least a couple of hours would be important as sometimes people solve things themselves and it gives it a chance to be solved by being on the new list.

Comment: Almost dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104700/allow-high-rep-users-to-almost-immediately-offer-bounties-though-at-an-extra-co.

Comment: Another very similar request: [It's time to remove the bounty delay](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210384/its-time-to-remove-the-bounty-delay).  Only the idea here of it being a privilege is why I haven't voted to close.

Answer (score 8):

I don't think it should be a privilege, and I actually don't like the idea itself. If you gain the privilege to almost instantly start a bounty, the community doesn't have the time to do standard moderation stuff, like closing it if appropriate.

A question that has been there for two days probably had some redacting which adds to the overall quality of the question, which is beneficial for the author of the question and possible for the users answering. You don't want the Fastest Gun in the West ruin a bounty question...

Comment: Oh, I didn't mean instantly - just sooner than 2 full days.  Someone who has a certain amount of reputation hopefully would generally post better quality (though not always of course).

Answer (score 4):

In addition to Patrick Hofman's answer, it's also about allowing natural answers to come through without the need for a bounty.

Regardless of this being abused (which is a valid issue), until some time has passed by users don't know whether a bounty is required or not.

Experts who answer are in different time zones all over the world, so you need to give at least 24 hours to let everyone a chance to see the question, arguably a bit more as people then come home from work etc. So 2 days is a natural length of time to wait to ascertain if a bounty is required.

You also don't want impatient users just posting bounties too soon, as if the question is good enough (not dupe etc) they'll get their answer.

Answer (score 3):

The version I will support is lowering the threshold to 24 hours instead of 48 hours, as 30k privilege.

This will both still give reasonable delay, and a good bonus for users with high reputation.

This can also be escalating, e.g. lower the threshold in 1 hour per 1000 reputation above X, but never less than 24 hours.