# Mandatory delay in offering a bounty

Tags: discussion, feature-request, bounties, timeline

What is the rationale for not allowing to post a bounty on my own question **right away**?  If my question is urgent enough for me to offer a bounty, why do I have to waste two days waiting?

**EDIT**:

I'm not asking about how to **get the answer** sooner.  I'm asking why can't I **offer a bounty** sooner.

Comment: If your question is _that_ urgent, have you considered hiring a professional instead of relying on a bunch of volunteers on the internet?

Comment: "waste two days waiting"? Why not spend two days researching your issue if it's that important?

Comment: @Yannis how does that not apply to expecting to ever get any answer from SO?  We're not a service optimized for free answers in two days.

Comment: @Yannis - I would consider this as well.  However, this is out of scope for my question here.  I just want to know why the decision for 2 days delay was made.

Comment: Agree, various somewhat snarky suggestions for the OP to work harder, research more, hire a consultant, and so forth are honestly not even germane to this question.  And I *know* these suggestions are snarky, because if they were actual answers to the question, you all would just post them as answers, not comments.

Comment: Also, I continue to be annoyed that it's impossible to ask for the rationale for something on meta without it being presumed that the OP wants to get rid of it.

Comment: Upvoted, and marked as duplicate. This is a reasonable question, and deserves a reasonable response.

Comment: I can't say that this is _the_ rationale, but we would have to allow closing bountied questions if the bounty could be started immediately.

Comment: @Telthien - Yes, it seems to be a duplicate.  I was not pointed towards the question that `Yannis` provided a link to while typing this one.

Comment: @ryan While George covers some philosophical aspects of this requirement, Marc [also brings up valid points](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/3372/155160). I think the same reasoning still applies today.

Comment: Question for more experienced metas.  I have what I believe to be an interesting and valid idea on how to give the OPs (of both this and the post it's a dupe of) what they're looking for while also handling all of the various concerns raised.  I've written it as an answer to the original question... where it's multiple screens down, with no votes, and seems unlikely to be seen by much of anyone.  What further should I do (if anything)?

Comment: @BenBarden: post it as a feature request rather than an answer to a discussion. Link back here & to the other question for context.